# Как получить значения свойств объекта при помощи for in loop?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая в результате выдает объект с датами

Задача: нужно вывести даты в качестве select options.

делаю такую конструкцию:

```
var deliveryDates = document.getElementById("deliveryDateSel")

var deliveryDatesObj = getDeliveryDates();

for (var prop in deliveryDatesObj) {

             deliveryDates.options[deliveryDates.options.length] = new Option(prop, prop);
         }
```

Но она выдает названия свойств, а не значения свойств.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос: Как получить именно значения свойств?**

Прототип здесь: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/58sexpvo/2/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var prop in deliveryDatesObj) {

        if (this.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(deliveryDatesObj, prop)) {
            deliveryDates.options[deliveryDates.options.length] = new Option(deliveryDatesObj[prop], deliveryDatesObj[prop]);
        }

    }
```